# Android. Google Ad's Can't resolve

Tags: android, ads

I have added some google ad's banners in my application, and they are still displaying google test banner. Is it right, please answer who know, thanks !!

Comment: Yes, you will only see test banners running from Android Studio and on your test devices as Google does not want developers creating applications with live ads and just making bots to click them.

Answer (score 0):

For Testing purposes, we need to use testing add ids only.
At the time of uploading apk into the Google Play console, we need to generate add ids in [Admob](https://admob.google.com/home/) and replace the test ids with original ids, then we will get real ads.